# Getting observable from model by String in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am writing a custom binding handler in Knockout.
I want to to pass a String like: `firstName` as the valueAccessor, then I want to get the observable firstName from my view model, but how do I get an observable by String?

Here is my code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DefaultOrCustom = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

        var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        // value will equal "firstName" at this phase
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a JavaScript object as an associative array, using your field name as the key (e.g. `object.foo` can be represented as `object['foo']`) .  Then, as you are pointing to an observable, you call it as a function to get / set the value.

Assuming you have a binding like this:

```
data-bind="DefaultOrCustom: 'firstName'"
```

You can access the observable like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DefaultOrCustom = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

    var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

    var oldValue = viewModel[value](); // read from the observable
    viewModel[value]('New Value');     // write to the observable 
}
```

---

You can get even more flexible by checking the type of the field.  If it is 'function' then treat it is an observable - using the () form, otherwise treat it as a regular field.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DefaultOrCustom = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

    var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    var oldValue;

    if (typeof(viewModel[value]) == 'function') {
      oldValue = viewModel[value]();   // read from the observable
      viewModel[value]('New Value');   // write to the observable
    } else {
      oldValue = viewModel[value];     // read from the field
      viewModel[value] = 'New Value';  // write to the field
    }
}
```

FYI: `typeof` is actually not a function, but I often find using this form makes it clearer what I am typing.

Comment: Instead of checking if it's a function (which will return true if it's any kind of object), use ko.utils.unwrapObservable() - which would simplify the code in addition to making it more robust